# SQL Database Design: Bad practice to have parent table with only primary key?

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database

My database holds two types of orders - internal and external. Since they are both order types I want them to share a primary key, which comes from the superentity 'RentOrder'. This design is shown below:

[image: Schema]

My questions:

1. Would it be considered bad practice that my RentOrder table contains only one column, which is the primary key - 'id'?
2. ExternalRentOrder and InternalRentOrder have a number of fields in common (e.g. orderDate, rentStartDate, rentEndDate etc.). Obviously these columns could be in the parent RentOrder table. However that would mean I would need to do a parent-child JOIN to get all InternalRentOrder or ExternalRentOrder data. This seems less efficient and performance is my priority. Is there a right way to do this and is my current solution ok?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not unreasonable.  That said, I usually have other columns in tables, such as:

- `createdAt` -- datetime row was inserted
- `createdBy` -- who created the row

In addition, common columns might also be helpful. In your case:

- `orderId`
- `supplierId`
- `orderDate`
- and so on.

In fact, there might be a fair amount of commonality, so you might find a single table is sufficient.  Separate tables are helpful if you want foreign key relationships to `InternalRentOrder` and/or to `ExternalRentOrder`.

Finally, a type column might also be helpful.  Depending on the database you are using, this can make it easier to ensure no duplication between the two tables.

Comment: @Ben123 Further to "type column", the way you would do it is have `RentOrder` have a type column as part of it's PK, then the other two tables also have the same, except their type columns are check constrained to a single value each. Then the FK becomes two columns `Id, Type` to `RentOrder`